# How to make vim short key for xelatex and pdflatex both?

Tags: xetex, vim

I have learned that the following setting in _vimrc will let `\ll` compile by engine `pdflatex`:

```
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -aux-directory=F:/Vim/my_latex_doc/temp --synctex=-1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
```

My problem is can be make some modification such that it will compiled by `xelatex` when I press `\lx`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this in your vimrc to quickly switch the compiler to `xelatex` with `\lx`.  Then use `\ll` to compile.

```
function SetXeTex()
    let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'xelatex -aux-directory=F:/Vim/my_latex_doc/temp --synctex=-1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
endfunction
map <Leader>lx :<C-U>call SetXeTex()<CR>
```

If you want to set `xelatex` temporarily and use `\lx` to compile you could use

```
function CompileXeTex()
    let oldCompileRule=g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf
    let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'xelatex -aux-directory=F:/Vim/my_latex_doc/temp --synctex=-1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
    call Tex_RunLaTeX()
    let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf=oldCompileRule
endfunction
map <Leader>lx :<C-U>call CompileXeTex()<CR>
```

Comment: That's it, It really works fine.